# Start and End times of the week

Tags: c#, timespan, dayofweek

I have this string that represents start time (in seconds from Midnight) and duration (in seconds) from Sunday to Saturday.

0 0 79200 21600 36000 18000 0 0 21600 43200 0 0 0 0

Broken down

0 0 means no start or end on Sunday
79200 21600 means start 10pm Monday end 4am Tuesday
36000 18000 means start 10am Tuesday end 3pm Tuesday
0 0 means no start or end on Wednesday
21600 43200 means start 6am Thursday end 6pm Thursday
0 0 means no start or end on Friday
0 0 means no start or end on Saturday

The above represents the following

[image: hours of days of week chart]

How can i report the start time and end times for each respective day. Taking into account that the window can span midnight.

I currently have this

```
int monstart;
TimeSpan monstartint = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(monstart);
int monduration;
int monend = monstart + monduration;
```

but this show the start time correctly, but its show the end as 1.04:00:00

I would like something like this

Monday     22:00:00  -->  Tuesday    04:00:00

Comment: Any reason you can't simply compare the result to one day and if it's greater then add one to the day and subtract one from the timespan?

Comment: Hi Ian, can you let me know how to do it?

Comment: Thanks @IanMercer. I've constructed something based on what you presented. It works well but I'll have to do it for each day. I'm not sure where to post what I've done. I want to know if I can construct a method (not sure that's what its called) so I can call it from my main program.

Comment: If you have an update to the question, edit the question with the update, maybe under a new heading 'Update'. If it begins to morph into a new question, mark this question as answered and open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use `string.Split` and `int.Parse` to get your values into two arrays: `startTimes` and `durations` of length 7 each.

```
for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++)
{
   TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(startTimes[day]);
   TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(durations[day]);
   TimeSpan end = start + duration;
   int endDay = day;

   if (end.TotalHours > 24)
   { 
       end = end - TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
       endDay = (endDay + 1)% 7;
   }

   // Period is from day, start to endDay, end
   // Convert day to (DayName) and output it 

}
```